# Subscript out of range - Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting a "Subscript out of range" error on line 9. I'm not a programmer and do not claim to be. For this reason I need a little help trying to get my Excel button to work. I only know a little VB. I'm at a loss because the button will execute the macro up to a certain point and then I get this error...

```
------Line 9:ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("strActiveWorksheet").Sort.SortFields.Clear-----
```

Here is the code:

```
'
' MakeParetoTable Macro
'
Dim strActiveWorkSheet As String
Sub MakeParetoTable()
strActiveWorkSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    Range("B6:B31,I6:I31").Select
    Range("Table2[[#Headers],[Total Quanity]]").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Range("P6").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("P:P").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("strActiveWorksheet").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("strActiveWorksheet").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Q7:Q31"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("strActiveWorksheet").Sort
        .SetRange Range("P6:Q31")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
    Application.WindowState = xlNormal
    Range("Q32").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-25]C:R[-1]C)"
    Range("Q33").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=1
    Range("R7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/R32C17"
    Range("R7").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("R7:R31"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("R7:R31").Select
    Range("S7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
    Range("S8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+RC[-1]"
    Range("S8").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("S8:S31"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("S8:S31").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you misspelled `"Quanity"` - it should be `"Quantity"`. Thus, the element is not found, and is considered "out of range".

Just saw the edit. You have a variable called `strActiveWorksheet`, but you are looking for a worksheet with the name `"strActiveWorksheet"`. You need to remove the quotes:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strActiveWorksheet).Sort.SortFields.Clear
```

and the same in the next line, and possibly other places in your code.  Just to explain (since you said you are a bit of a newbie in VBA):

Something like `"hello"` is a string (constant). You can assign a string to a variable

```
Dim goodbye
goodbye = "hello"

MsgBox goodbye
```

will display "hello"

But

```
MsgBox "goodbye"
```

will display "goodbye".

Make sense?

Comment: +1 probably the cause also worth checking `strActiveWorksheet` sheet name spelling and make sure you qualify Ranges properly.

Comment: wow you're the man. It was exactly what you said. Sometimes an extra set of eyes goes a long way!

Comment: yes sir. that makes sense to me. I just need to practice more and pay attention to detail.

Comment: "Extra set of eyes" - so true. And computers are great for teaching you (the hard way) that details matter! If you are happy that this solves your problem, you may mark the answer as "accepted" with the little check mark...

Comment: + 1 Nicely explained :)